# SQL Server Merge replication - Applying the snapshot to the Subscriber manually and not via GUI

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, merge-replication

I am having issues finding material on how to send a snapshot to a subscriber server to apply the snapshot at a later stage.

My situation: Publisher is based in SA. Subscriber is based in Germany. To deliver a 8GB database snapshot takes almost a day and I  have heard if you zip the snapshot and copy it to the subscriber server via google drive or FTP you can speed the process up. Has anyone dealt with this ? Using SQL Server 2014 Merge rep.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to deliver Snapshots via FTP, check the docs:

[How to: Deliver a Snapshot Through FTP (Replication Transact-SQL Programming)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146956(v=sql.105).aspx)

> To enable FTP snapshot delivery for a **merge publication**
>   At the Publisher on the publication database, execute `sp_addmergepublication`. Specify @publication, a value of true for @enabled_for_internet and appropriate values for the following parameters:
>
> @**ftp_address** - the address of the FTP server used to deliver the snapshot.
>
> (Optional) @**ftp_port** - the port used by the FTP server.
>
> (Optional) @**ftp_subdirectory** - the subdirectory of the default FTP directory assigned to an FTP login. For example, if the FTP server root is \ftpserver\home and you want snapshots to be stored at \ftpserver\home\snapshots, specify \snapshots\ftp for @ftp_subdirectory (replication appends 'ftp' to the snapshot folder path when it creates snapshot files).
>
> (Optional) @**ftp_login** - a login account used when connecting to the FTP server.
>
> (Optional) @**ftp_password** - the password for the FTP login.

However, if you do in-depth search for replication and FTP at SO you will find that people report some problems with snapshot delivery over FTP, namely when setting up FTP delivery Publisher or Subscriber may request a direct link between each other during initialization, like in this question: [SQL Server replication using FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161749/sql-server-replication-using-ftp) .